# Remove panda labels

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to insert some data in an excel file column through python. I am using panda to insert and write data in existing excel file.

```
41  5   5

40  96  5

25  5   3

12  6   29
```

But it disturbs whole structure and deletes some data.

```
41  0   5   5

0   10  96  5

1   20  5   3

2   30  6   29

3   20

4   15

5   30

6   45
```

I only want to insert my data without ant datalabels. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

import win32com.client

xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

wkbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\PycharmProjects\\untitled1\\arrays.xlsx")

wksht = wkbk.ActiveSheet;

wksht.Columns(2).EntireColumn.Insert()

xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save()

xlApp.Quit()

from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('arrays.xlsx')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('arrays.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

writer.book = book

writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

data = [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

writer.save()
```

Answer (score 4):

From your example, it looks like you write out your dataframe labels and column headers. You can suppress these using the  `index=False` `header=False` options in the `to_excel` method:

```
df.to_excel(index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: It removes row labels but doesn't remove column labels. It shows this output:  
0  5 5

10  96 5

20  5 3

30  6 29
20   
15   
30   
45

Comment: I have updated the answer with the header=False option, does this solve your problem?

Comment: Splendid! Glad to hear that!